# Why does YUI transitions use fixed heights?

Tags: yui

So I'm trying to add animations/transitions using YUI and I'm wondering why on earth it uses fixed heights?

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/transition/transition-basic.html

What's the deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

The examples you mean? They do not have to, they are just poor examples. YUI Transition can use all possible values, it even support completely dynamic animations like so:

```
// Will create a slideDown effect on #thing

Y.one('#thing').transition({
    height: function(node) {
        return node.get('scrollHeight') + 'px';
    },
    duration: 0.1,
    easing: 'ease-out',
    on: {
        start: function() {
            var overflow = this.getStyle('overflow');
            if (overflow !== 'hidden') { // enable scrollHeight/Width
                this.setStyle('overflow', 'hidden');
                this._transitionOverflow = overflow;
            }
        },
        end: function() {
            if (this._transitionOverflow) { // revert overridden value
                this.setStyle('overflow', this._transitionOverflow);
                delete this._transitionOverflow;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This example will expand an element that was previously `0px` high to its expected height.